# Why am I getting “undefined is not an object (evaluating PropTypes.shape)”?

Tags: react-native

When i running my android emulator i got the error:

> Why am I getting “undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   PropTypes.shape)”?

I know that React removed PropTypes from their core library as of React 15.5.
In all my code I use:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you edit the question to add some code where you are using `PropTypes`? Also, have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910731/why-am-i-getting-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-proptypes-shape)?

Comment: @UzairA. I've got it, have updated the react-redux library, thanks for help!

Comment: Glad to know that! :)